# Unable to different if data.length > 0 on response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I am working on a React native project where I query a search phrase.
However, in my conditional statement, I am getting `Not empty` regardless of whether or not the array has data inside of it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the first array, if it found a matching server-side query:

```
[
    {
        "document": {
            "name": "projects/warrenty-7707e/databases/(default)/documents/users/HBC/warrentycard/d4XgBWIywU6K2fZ7ix0j",
            "fields": {
                "comment": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                },
                "model": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                },
                "createDate": {
                    "timestampValue": "2019-06-27T11:04:47.031Z"
                },
                "product": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                },
                "exp_date": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                },
                "plate": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                },
                "email": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                },
                "name": {
                    "stringValue": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And here is the array if it didn't match:

```
[
    {}
]
```

Either way, in the following conditional, I only get `Not Empty` returned to me. Any ideas?

````
if (this.state.serverData.length > 0) {
    return (

        <View>
<Text>Not empty</Text>
</View>
    )

} else {
<View>
<Text>empty</Text>
</View>
} ```
````

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: the if function always returns 
        <View>
<Text>Not empty</Text>
</View>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, the result array you get from the server is not empty even if there are no search results.

You could check if the length of the data is not 0 (which you are doing) as well as if the first object is not empty.

```
    if (this.state.serverData.length > 0 && Object.keys(this.state.serverData[0]).length !== 0 ) {
        return (<View>
                <Text>Not empty</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return (<View>
    <Text>empty</Text>
    </View>);
```